# The angle between two subspaces can not be too small

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, angle

**Some context.**

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subspaces of dimension $k$ of $\mathbb R^{2k}$. Let's define $\psi(A,B)$, the *sinus of the angle* between $A$ and $B$ as

$$\psi(A,B)=\min_{\substack{a\in A\setminus\{0\}\\ b\in B\setminus\{0\}}} \vert\sin\widehat{(a,b)}\vert.$$

We can notice that the angle between a vector $b$ and a subspace $A$ is

$$\psi(b,A)=\vert\sin\widehat{(b,p_A(b))}\vert$$

where $p_A$ is the orthogonal projection onto $A$.

**What we know.**

We know that there exists $b_1,\ldots,b_k\in B$ linearly independents such that

- for all $i\ne j$, $\widehat{(b_i,b_j)}\geqslant \pi/4$ ;
- there exists a constant $c_1>0$ such that

$$\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,k\},\quad \vert\sin\widehat{(b_i,p_A(b_i))}\vert\geqslant c_1$$

where $p_A$ is the orthogonal projection onto $A$.

**What we want to prove.**

> Can we prove that: if $c_1$ is sufficiently small, there exists a constant $c_2$ (depending on $c_1$) such that
>
> $$\psi(A,B)\geqslant c_2 \quad?$$

**Final remarks.**

I haven't made any progress yet, so any hints, references or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the $b_i$ somehow "independent"? As written nothing prevents them from being identical.

Comment: In any case, for any fixed $b \in B$, I think the minimum angle with a point on $A$ is going to be attained by $p_A(b_i)$. So it is a matter of interpolating the known inequality involving $c_1$ to get an inequality involving $c_2$. Presumably if the $b_i$ are just linearly independent without any explicit control on the angle between them, then it could be that $c_2 \gg c_1$ but still finite.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the comment you are right. The $b_i$ are indeed linearly independents, but we don't know anything else on them.

Comment: @Ian You are right about $p_A(b_i)$ which realise the angle between $b_i$ and $A$. And I don't mind a big $c_2$ (in fact the bigger the better), but I am afraid $c_2$ could be arbitrary close to $0$.

Comment: So basically this interpolation amounts to saying, what is the behavior of the angle between $v:=\sum_{I=1}^n c_i b_i$ and $p_A(v)=p_A \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i b_i \right ) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i p_A(b_i)$. So you want to control $\frac{\langle v,p_A(v) \rangle}{\| v \| \| p_A(v) \|}$. The problem now is that there are cross terms: you need to somehow know something about $\langle b_i,p_A(b_j) \rangle$.

Comment: Also sorry I meant $c_2 \ll c_1$.

Comment: @Ian I absolutely agree with you, you have nicely summarise the problem here. Thanks for the insight, I will look in this direction.

Comment: It might help to play with the case $k=2$: can you choose planes $A,B$ so that knowing $\langle b_i,p_A(b_i) \rangle$ doesn't tell you much about the size of $\langle b_i,p_A(b_2) \rangle$? Can you do this independent of the overall size of $p_A(b_i)$?

Comment: @Ian I am working in this direction, but not much progress for now.

Comment: @Ian I have asked a quite similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683668/the-angle-between-two-subspaces-of-mathbb-rn-can-not-be-too-small) if you want to check it out.